# Looping through nested object with jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the items in an array with jQuery but it's just returning `[object] [Object]`. What am I doing wrong here?

There data is returned in this format:

```
Object
1:{gps: "0.000,0.000", street_name: "First Street", street_name_alt: "1st Street"}
2:{gps: "0.000,0.000", street_name: "Second Street", street_name_alt: "2nd Street"}
```

And I am trying to output it with:

```
$.each( data.street, function( key, val ) {                       
        htm+='<ons-list-item id="'+key+'">';
        htm+=' '+val;
        htm+='</ons-list-item>';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is your object and key is index..

You have to try accessing it's properties. For ex to access `street_name`

```
$.each( data.street, function( key, val ) {                       
        htm+='<ons-list-item id="'+key+'">';
        htm+=' '+val.street_name;
        htm+='</ons-list-item>';
});
```

It's not a multi dimensional array btw, it's a nested object.

Comment: Ooooh, I see what I did wrong. It's working now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = {};
data.street = [{gps: "0.000,0.000", street_name: "First Street", street_name_alt: "1st Street"},
{gps: "0.000,0.000", street_name: "Second Street", street_name_alt: "2nd Street"}];

var htm = "";
// updated the arguments to reflect their functions better.
$.each( data.street, function( index, element ) {                       
        htm+='<ons-list-item id="'+index+'">';
        htm+=' '+element .street_name;
        htm+='</ons-list-item>';
});
console.log(htm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's because `val` refers to the full object. Use the property names to get the right result.